# JMS communication between WAS 6 and JBOSS EAP 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, jms, hornetq, jboss-mdb

I have an application deployed in Websphere which should push a message in a queue implemented in JBoss using HornetQ. That message will then be consumed by an MDB within another application (on JBoss). Is that even possible?

In summary:
WAS (producer) -> JBoss (consumer)

I think yes because the protocol JMS is shared, but what are the details? should I load JBoss with MQ libraries or is it all in the way I refer to the JBoss queue from WAS?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If the MDB deployed on JBoss EAP is receiving a message from a local queue in HornetQ, then you do not need to deploy any MQ jars.

All you will need to do is write a MDB application and read the messages in your `onMessage(Message msg)` method. It should be really as simple as that.

You can see an example of a MDB in the jboss eap [quick start](https://github.com/jboss-eap/quickstart/tree/master-eap6/helloworld-mdb) . The `HelloWorldQueueMDB.java` class is the one you might be interested in. Follow the code in that class and modify the destination annotation value for your particular HornetQ queue name (from `standalone-full.xml` or `standalone-full-ha.xml` or the `full` or `full-ha` profile in your `domain.xml` file).

On a side note, JBoss EAP 6.1 is quite old. I would highly recommend upgrading to JBoss EAP 6.4.13 or later.

Comment: yeah I know it's old but I have customer constraints about that. Thank you for the info on the jboss side (the mdb is already up and running) but what about the websphere side? How do I insert a message in the queue on the other server?

Comment: I do not know much about Websphere MQ. I would assume you will need to create a JMS producer to send the message as all standard JMS protocol does.